# Create flash turntable

Tags: apache-flex, flash

I need to be able to generate .swf files (or any other formats I can use inside Flex) of a scene.

Not the traditional panorama where you stand in the center and look around, but one where you rotate around the object/scene. Turntable?

Often used to showcase products, as you can rotate them (generated from several images rendered of the object at different angles).

Any free software for this?

I want is to generate `.swf` files of different scenes, that I can use in my software. These components should be turntables. If I click and drag the mouse on the swf, I will be able to rotate around the object/scene. Like an inverted panorama viewer. This is achieved by rendering several images in a 360 degree angle around the object, and scrolling through these images as I drag to rotate around.

I've already made it in Flex, but I was wandering if there where any tools to do this for me so that it will be lighter.

Right now, I buffer 180 frames to memory, and I swap out the images when I drag the view.

I guess I'm not good at explaining. Check this: http://productorbit.com/

Ignore the generating process. I use 3D rendered material. What I want is the resulting turntable of the heli as shown below the video on that page.

Comment: I think you'll need to explain it a little better Stian.Start with what you want.

Comment: Scripts/flashes on that site seem so heavy that they had literally locked up by browser (Chrome v24) and I had to kill it via TaskManager. Not good, not good!

Comment: oh, sry. Works like a charm over here.
Well, I'll just try and play around with it and see if I can come up with something myself ;)

Comment: Hm.. you know, that had to be problem of mine. After restart, it works smoothly. Strange. Sorry for the alarm.